# Whitespace appearing in webpage after horizontally minimizing browser

Tags: html, css, vue.js, overflow

Here's the webpage:
[image]
Here's what happens after horizontal minimizing of the browser window (overflow appears, scrolled all the way to the right):
[image]

As you can see, a whitespace appears. My guess is it's due to a specified width being set somewhere. however I don't understand why this is the behavior.

Here's some code:

```
<template>
  <div class="dashboardContainer">
    <div class="dashHeader">
        <TopPuddle class="backgroundPuddles topPuddle" />
        <RightPuddle class="backgroundPuddles rightPuddle" />
    </div>
    <div class="dashFooter"></div>

    <div class="dashboardView d-flex flex-row">
      <div class="navBarContainer">
        <NavigationBar />
      </div>

      <div class="dashComponentView">
        <router-view></router-view>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

The relevant styles:

```
.dashboardContainer {
  height: 3000px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 10%);
}

.navBarContainer {
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 300px;
}

.dashHeader {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: span 1;
  @extend %default-background-color;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dashFooter {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 11;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: span 1;
  background: #e5e5e5;
  z-index: 2;
}

.backgroundPuddles {
  position: absolute;
}

.topPuddle {
  top: 0px;
  right: 150px;
}

.rightPuddle {
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

.dashboardView {
  height: 3000px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
}

.dashComponentView {
  flex-grow: 1;  
}
```

Components are rendered in the `<router-view></router-view>`

Here's the skeleton of a component:

```
<template>
  <div class="d-flex flex-column dashContainer">
     xxxxx
  </div>
</template>
```

the styles:

```
.dashContainer {
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: calc((100vw - 300px - 1000px) / 2);
}
```

and finally App.vue:

```
<template>
  <router-view />
</template>

<style>
</style>
```

As you can see, I'm not declaring an explicit width anywhere. Could anyone tell me why this is occurs? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to set:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

This should fix any overflow on the page, and if it doesn't, you can also try:

```
max-width: 100vw;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

This sets the page's maximum width, and doesn't allow it to go over.

Comment: I see, however I'd like for them to be able to scroll the page you know... I just don't want the white space to appear... surely this should be possible

Comment: Well, the overflow-x property targets specifically the X co-ordinate, thus you should be able to scroll vertically still.

Comment: horizontally scroll the page is what I meant

Comment: In this case, you should be able to set max-width to the full page's desired width in VW units, not necessarily 100.

Comment: Setting the overflow-x to hidden does seem like an acceptable alternative solution but it isn't exactly what I was looking for